# c# sort by elements or attribute with one method

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, attributes, element

I need to sort xml documents sometimes by attributes, sometimes by elements, depending on what type of documents comes in. How can I use one sortBy method in c# to solove this problem? Many thanks for your help! For example my sorting key is "bookID"element or attribute, and the xml files are:

```
 <bookstore>
  <book>
    <bookID>100</bookID>
    <name> The cat in the hat <name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>90</bookID>
    <name> another book <name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>103</bookID>
    <name> a new book <name>
  </book>
  </bookstore>
```

or sometimes the xml comes in the below format:

```
<bookstore>
  <book bookID="100">The cat in the hat</book> 
  <book bookID="90">another book</book> 
  <book bookID="103"> a new book</book> 
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle both possibilities in your query, assuming you are using Linq-to-XML for this. You might utilize the `let` keyword, but the basic idea is to check for either the attribute or the element for null and use the appropriate value.

```
var books = from book in document.Element("bookstore").Elements("book")
            let bookId = book.Attribute("bookID") != null 
                ? book.Attribute("bookID").Value 
                : book.Element("bookID").Value
            orderby int.Parse(bookId)
            select book; // project properties of book as needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! somehow bookId = book.Attribute("bookID") != null soes not work for me. It always returns true whether there is attribute or not..

Comment: Is "bookID" of a differing case in your actual XML? I took both your XML snippets (and had to clean one up, your "name" elements are not properly closed) and the code executed successfully on each.