# c# select attribute or element from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, attributes, element

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <bookID>100</bookID>
    <name> The cat in the hat </name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>90</bookID>
    <name> another book </name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>103</bookID>
    <name> a new book </name>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I'm trying to sellect the bookID value from a XML document.The method I currently use is `Element(bookID).Value` But sometimes the bookID comes as an attribute of book like this: `<book bookID=100>` Is there a way of doing that in c#, like a xPath expression maybe? Many thanks!

Comment: You should make sure your XML structure is fixed by a schema before you start dealing with it. It will save you from a lot of trouble later.

Comment: what's the problem with solution suggested in [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778330/c-sharp-sort-by-elements-or-attribute-with-one-method)?

Comment: @har07 I am googling let key word and trying to understand that solution. That's why I haven't responded yet. I am quite new to C#. Apologies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath, you can use union (`|`) operator to combine query that return different part of the XML. For example :

```
//book/bookID/text() | //book/@bookID
```

The above XPath returns text content of `bookID` element and `bookID` attribute in document order. See the demo which using `XmlDocument.SelectNodes()` to execute the XPath.

**[Demo Codes](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GIuk6z) :**

```
var xml = @"<bookstore>
  <book>
    <bookID>100</bookID>
    <name> The cat in the hat </name>
  </book>
  <book bookID='90'>
    <name> a new book </name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>103</bookID>
    <name> another book </name>
  </book>
</bookstore>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var result = doc.SelectNodes("//book/bookID/text() | //book/@bookID");
foreach (XmlNode r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Value);
}
```

**output :**

```
100
90
103
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this need to be an XPath expression or can you use `Linq` with the `XDocument` system.

For example.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(@"<bookstore>
                                <book>
                                <bookID>100</bookID>
                                <name> The cat in the hat </name>
                                </book>
                                <book bookID=""90"">
                                <name> another book </name>
                                </book>
                                <book>
                                <bookID>103</bookID>
                                <name> a new book </name>
                                </book>
                                </bookstore>");

foreach (var xBook in xDocument.Descendants("book"))
{
    var bookIdNode = xBook.Elements("bookID").FirstOrDefault();
    int bookId = 0;

    ///there is a book id as an element
    if (bookIdNode != null)
    {
        //invalid book id.. should be an int
        if (!int.TryParse(bookIdNode.Value, out bookId))
            continue;
    }
    else
    {
        var bookIdAttr = xBook.Attributes("bookID").FirstOrDefault();
        if (bookIdAttr == null || !int.TryParse(bookIdAttr.Value, out bookId))
            continue;
    }

    if (bookId == 0)
        continue;

    //else we got our book id

}
```

This code is quite simple, just enumerates over the descendants with the element name `book`. It first checks if there is an element named `bookID` (case sensitive). If there is it attempts to parse the book id out as an `int` using the method `int.TryParse()`.

If there are no `bookID` elements it next checks if there are any attributes with the name `bookID` and grabs the first instance (or null) using `FirstOrDefault()` extension method. If there is an instance of the `bookID` attribute it also try to parse the int using the `int.TryParse()` method.

By the end of the small snippet we have then check if the `bookId` is `0` if it is zero we can assume something went wrong. However this shouldnt happen as the logic should keep enumerating and forget about Elements without a `bookID` element or `bookID` attribute.